# Synergy fails to launch! (Ubuntu 10.10 64 bit)

Tags: 64-bit, ubuntu-10.10, launcher

Synergy will not launch on ubuntu 10.10 64bit.

I have tried:
-rebooting
-removing and reinstalling Synergy
-using previous stable and beta versions

but still nothing, any advice on the next steps I can take?

Comment: Does it give you any errors?  Is it the server or the client that's failing to start?  Are you using the CLI tools or some interface like QuickSynergy?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass synergy a command line parameter to log everything:

```
synergys --log /tmp/synergys.log
```

You can pass the --log to the client side as well.  If you're using a GUI utility to do this, there should be an option somewhere to set Synergy to output a log file. Running from the terminal, though, would be the best option to troubleshoot.

Unfortunately you're not clear enough on whether you're using Synergy with a GUI, if the Ubuntu box is the client, or things like that.